# Is it possible to avoid jxls range transformation?

Tags: java, jxls

I have an excel template, with two sheets. Both have a foreach, that prints some data in the final excel file. However, in the second sheet I need to have reference values in the first sheet that are inside foreach too.

So the problem, is that, jxls will transform the formulas in the second sheet as a range, and I want a direct relation.
For example:

```
Sheet1
A1  -->  <jx:forEach items="${departments}" var="department">
A2  -->        ${department.name} | ${department.chief}
A3  -->  </jx:forEach>

Sheet2
A1  -->  'Sheet 1'!A2
```

After processing data values, assuming we have 3 departments, I'll have something like:

```
Sheet1
A2  ---> department1
A3  ---> department2
A4  ---> department3

Sheet2

A2  ---> #VALUE       (PROBLEM: This happens because jxls references 'Sheet 1'!A1:A3)
A3  ---> #VALUE       (PROBLEM: This happens because jxls references 'Sheet 1'!A2:A3)
A4  ---> department3  (PROBLEM: In this case it works, because range one only element - 'Sheet 1'!A3:A3)
```

Is it possible to avoid or workaround this behaviour?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need use $[*formula*] to formula in jxls.
In this case, the sheet2 in cell A1 should be $['Sheet 1'!A2].